# How to move a file with python, using %username% in destination path

Tags: python

I can't manage to make this code work

```
import os

source = "juan.txt"
destination = "C:\\Users\\%username%\\Desktop\\juan.txt"

try:
    if os.path.exists(destination):
        print("There is already a file there")
    else:
        os.replace(source, destination)
        print(source, "was moved")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
```

When I change **%username%** to my actual username it works, but I really need code that will allow me to replace this placeholder with the same value without the user knowing it.

Comment: Use a f-string.  Can you pickup the username from `os.environ`?  It's odd that  you have a `source` variable yet the value which value is already a suffix of the `destination` variable.  Why not extract the last path element from destination instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is getting the user login name. You can do it this way:

```
username = os.getlogin()
destination = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Desktop\\juan.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use format:

```
destination = "C:\\Users\\{}\\Desktop\\juan.txt"

...

destination.format(myvar)
```

or in python 3.6 +

```
destination = f"C:\\Users\\{myvar}\\Desktop\\juan.txt"
```